# how to break exec --stdin input from a pod container?

Tags: kubernetes, terminal

How to break input sequence when `--stdin` is added to a pod `exec`?

I tried with `ctrl` + `c` or `exit` but they did not work. please check following screenshot.

[image]

Of course this happens when closing bracket `)` is not added but in such scenario, the terminal is stuck with infinite input!

Answer (score 0):

Try with `ctrl` + `z`. Then `exit` should get you to your console.

Comment: that did not work with `ctrl` + `z`